# Graficar CSV tkinter, Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, matplotlib

Estoy graficando un CSV con Matplotlib. Tengo una función `browseFiles()` la cual carga el archivo CSV y la grafica... pero necesito que esta función solo cargue el archivo y tener otra función con un botón aparte para que grafique el archivo.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

root = Tk()
root.title('test')
root.geometry('400x200')

def graph():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df.plot()
    plt.show()

def browseFiles(): 
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = (("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
    data = pd.read_csv(filename,delimiter=',')
    print(data)
    data.plot()
    plt.show()

# my_button = Button(root,
#                    text='Graficar!', command=graficar)

button_explore = Button(root,  
                        text = "Browse Files", 
                        command = browseFiles)
# my_button.pack()
button_explore.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

En el botón `my_button` que tienes comentado (Supongo que porque no te ha funcionado ese código) tienes el argumento `command=graficar`, pero no tienes ninguna función que se llame `graficar` tienes una que se llama `graph`

Ahora, para poder lograr que con un botón obtengas el `dataframe` y lo imprimas y con otro botón diferente grafiques el `dataframe` que cargaste anteriormente debes utilizar una [variable global](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp)

De esa forma puedes guardar el `dataframe` desde una función y graficarlo desde otra

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

root = Tk()
root.title('test')
root.geometry('400x200')

#Definimos la variable global
data = None

#Función para graficar
def graph():
    #Utilizamos la variable global
    global data
    data.plot()
    plt.show()

#Función para cargar el dataframe
def browseFiles():
    #Utilizamos la variable global
    global data
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = (("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
    data = pd.read_csv(filename,delimiter=',')
    print(data)

#Botón para graficar, el argumento command siempre debe apuntar a una función existente, en este caso graph
button_graph = Button(root,  
                        text = "Graficar", 
                        command = graph)

button_explore = Button(root,  
                        text = "Browse Files", 
                        command = browseFiles)

button_explore.pack()
button_graph.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en que momento se le asigna el valor a la variable global data?

Comment: En esta línea `data = pd.read_csv(filename,delimiter=',')`